# Problem to get Typescript working in Visual Studio Code on MacOS-catalina

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I am trying to solve this issue. It seems to be an environment issue, but how to solve it ? how to connect the installed TSC to my console ?

Steps to Reproduce :

- `npm install -g typescript` seems to install or update typescript@3.8.3 correctly
- but then `tsc -v` says `tsc: command not found`
  same steps in video
- Console says (when trying to disable extensions) `bash: code: command not found`

my config :

```
VSCode Version: 1.43.1
Node.js : 12.8.1
OS Version: Darwin x64 19.3.0
Apple Model :   MacBook Pro 14,3
MacOS : Catalina 10.15.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with your PATH environment variable. Try `echo $PATH` in your terminal. It should display the list of your sytem paths which should include `/usr/local/bin` where `tsc` is located (same configuration as yours).

Comment: echo $PATH : 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/.npm:/.npm-global ... tsc in in .npm-global  exactly in /Users/jeancharlesamey/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc

Comment: When trying to launch a watch on tsconfing.json in Visual Code Studio, I am getting this error message : "The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object"